# A question regarding object release

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The below code is from Apple's GKRocket iPhone demo app:

```
- (void) peerListDidChange:(SessionManager *)session;
{
    NSArray *tempList = peerList;
    peerList = [session.peerList copy];
    [tempList release];
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

I am new to objective c and was wondering if **tempList** really need to be release?  My instinct and tells me is not because it did not retain the pointer.  Maybe I am not seeing the whole picture.

If it does require a release, can someone with more experience please explain why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess. I haven't used that sample project before.

A new pointer to the old `peerList` array is created, called `tempList`:

```
NSArray *tempList = peerList;
```

The code makes a copy of `session.peerList` and assigns the `peerList` pointer to that new copy:

```
peerList = [session.peerList copy];
```

The old `peerList`, which is actually now pointed to by `tempList`, can then be released safely:

```
[tempList release];
```

If you had assigned `[session.peerList copy];` right away, the old array would have no more retained pointers left, and if it wasn't autoreleased it would be a memory leak.

If you had assigned `tempList` but not released it, it leaks memory for the same reason, but the purpose of `tempList` is purely so the program knows what to release when you call `release` anyway.

Comment: Oh, I see why it needs to be release now.  Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just do: 
if(peerList) [peerList release];
peerList = [session.peerList copy];

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of this project actually crashes at this point in the code. session.peerList is NSMutableArray - and the app crashes when it tries to assign it to tempList. I modified the code to stop the crash. This is the declaration for peerList:

```
@interface GameLobbyController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, SessionManagerLobbyDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {
NSMutableArray  *peerList;
UIAlertView *alertView;
SessionManager *manager;}
```

This is the new version of the peerListDidChange method:

```
- (void) peerListDidChange:(SessionManager *)session;{
peerList = session.peerList;
[self.tableView reloadData];}
```

Not sure, but I think all that tempList code was simply to handle the switch from mutable to fixed array. Obviously I don't understand why it was so important for the peerList property to be fixed rather than mutable. All comments welcome.

Comment: Possible memory leak if peerList is pointing to something that is not autorelease.

Comment: Thanks - I have modified it to: NSArray *tempPeerList = [session.peerList copy];
    peerList = tempPeerList; It still won't let me use "release" because of ARC